# tabularx shifted farer than margin

Tags: margins, tabularx

I have a custom papersize and margins set with `geometry` package. Now I want a table to reach over the complete page (not the margins)

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
   \hline
   label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
   \hline 
   item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

now the table has the wished width but is shifted a bit to the right
(I used `\usepackage{showframe}` so you can see where the tabular should start and end)

[image: pic]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` simply inserts a table at the point where the environment is called.  In your case, you do it at the beginning of line where usually an indent is inserted as well.  You can simply suppress the indentation with `\noindent`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
  \hline
  label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
  \hline 
  item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3ex}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
  \hline
  label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
  \hline 
  item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image]